# BackupPC can't finish backup

Tags: backup, rsync

I'm trying to backup /etc/ directory on CentOS 5.2 using BackupPC.
It takes several hours and then aborted by signal ALRM.
There is a partial backup created with all data from /etc
But BackupPC thinks the backup is failed and always starts doing full backup again.

If I try to run rsync manually from the backup server it works flawlessly and finishes in about 5-10 seconds.

I have additional server with several GB of data I'm backing up and it works without a problem.

Comment: How do you do the backup when doing it automatically? What script is run, where does the output go, what does the output say?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with BackupPC, but check for any special files (e.g. sockets), symlink loops, or links to dirs outside of `/etc`:  `ls -lad \`find -L /etc \! \( -type f -or -type d \)\``

Comment: @KianTern were you able to solve, I'm having the same error

Answer (score 1):

There was some changes in the course of BackupPC version 3.X that was incompatible with rsync 3.2.3

See https://github.com/backuppc/backuppc/issues/369

We had the same problem and solved it by adding `--protocol=28` in the main configuration (Xfer) with the `RsyncArgs` parameter.

Alternatively, you can also edit the config.pl with the following:

```
$Conf{RsyncArgs} = [
  '--numeric-ids',
  '--perms',
  '--owner',
  '--group',
  '-D',
  '--links',
  '--hard-links',
  '--times',
  '--block-size=2048',
  '--recursive',
  '--protocol=28'
];
```

(only the **last line is important**, you might want to keep the rest unchanged)

Then if you have Ubuntu clients, you might want to check with the following arguments:

```
$Conf{RsyncArgsExtra} = [
  '--open-noatime',
  '--no-msgs2stderr'
];
```

on their respective `<name_of_host>.pl` files

For Debian 10 (Buster) servers, you only need to have `--noatime` in their specific config (`RsyncArgsExtra`)